# Hahn Banach Theorem problem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

How do we show that if $f(x)=f(y)$ for every bounded linear functional $f$ on a normed space $X$, then $x=y$.

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to if $f(x)=0$ for every $f$ then $x=0$. If $x$ is not zero, then we can define a functional $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}x$ (or $\mathbb{C}x$ etc.) by $\phi(\lambda x)=\lambda$. Then by Hahn-Banach extension theorem, we can extend this $\phi$ to be defined on the whole space, denoted also by $\phi$. Thus $\phi(x)=1\neq 0$. So $x$ has to be zero.

Comment: You need a sublinear function to control $\phi$, i.e why $\phi$ is bounded?

Comment: Bounded by the norm function $p(x)=||x||$.

Answer (score 3):

One application of *Hahn-Banach* Theorem is the  following:
$$ \text{If } x\in X \text{ and } x\not=0,\ \exists\ f\in X^*\ \ s.t.\\ \|f\|=1\text{ and } f(x)=\|x\|
$$
Hence, if $x-y\not=0$, there exists a bounded linear functional $f$ such that
$$ \|f\|=1\quad f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)=\|x-y\|\not=0
$$